# Is there a way to search for a string in all fields on a table and return a a field based on where the string was found?

Tags: sql, search, case

Is there a way to search for a string on all fields within a table and return a field linked to the field where it was found? Other than by writing a when condition?

For example on this table I would be searching for the 'date audit closed' and then return the value where the date is present. So the query would look like:

```
case
    when customfield1_name = 'date audit closed' then customfield1_value
    when customfield2_name = 'date audit closed' then customfield2_value
    when customfield3_name = 'date audit closed' then customfield3_value
end as 'datefield'
```

The table consists of over 50 fields in which the string can be located in any of them. [table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMOU0.png)
And then another 50 fields where the value may be located.

Comment: Well, a bad data model results in bad queries

Comment: 1. What if it is in more than 1 column?
2. If it is cumbersome to write, you can use dynamic query